# Using System.getProperty("os.name") in a mobile-test-class do not deliver os.name of connected device

Tags: android, ios, appium

I just wanted to get the os.name of the mobile device I am testing on. Is there a way to get the os.name from mobile devices?

Used System.getProperty("os.name");

I expected the output of "Android" or "iOS" but actually I got the output "Mac OS X".

Comment: Please share a bit code, how to you initialize the `driver` ? and you language program.

Answer (score 0):

The command that you mentioned returns the Operating system (Windows/Mac/Linux..etc).

There is two way to finding the platform (OS) of a device in appium:

**1) With driver()**

```
driver.getPlatformName();
```

You can pass it to a variable:

```
String platformUsed=driver.getPlatformName();
```

**2) By reading desired capabilities:**

```
driver.getCapabilities().getCapability("platformName").toString();
```

This will return you the platform name set in desired capabilities.

So If you want to get device information before creating driver or at run time (to check correct information of connected device) then you have to use the following to get device OS version. (adb for android and instruments for iOS)

For android:

```
adb -s " + deviceID + " shell getprop ro.build.version.release
```

For iOS :

```
instruments -s devices
```

Hope this helps.